# Error 500 when running Rails in Google App Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run my application in google app engine, I get up normally and even works the endpoint, but when several requests the same, give **500 error**, with the message:

> Internal Server Error
>   uninitialized constant Concurrent :: Promises

I have nothing that uses this in my application.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to check your logs(where 500 error is described)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an already [closed issue on google-cloud-ruby](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/2890). You may need to update your gem by running:

```
$ gem update google-cloud-ruby
```

Comment: Thank you ErvalhouS